# Need to build list of group members

Tags: windows-server-2008, dsquery

I have a server with its own local Groups. These groups hold AD users. I use them to apply permissions for the user in a web app. I need to generate a list of all the users in the group.

This is the script I'm trying to use:

```
dsquery group -samid "MyGroup" | dsget group "MyGroup" -members >c:\List.txt
```

I've tried many generations of this code and all I get are errors. At least this one creates a text file before it errors (with nothing in it).

So what am I doing wrong (I confess I'm new to this command line tool).

EDIT: the error I'm getting is "dsget failed:Value for 'Target object for this command' has incorrect format."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I too am a newbie.

But I beleive you want is:

```
dsquery group -name "MyGroup" | dsget group -members > c:\List.txt
```

Where you replace "MyGroup" with the name of the group you are looking for. If looking for multiple groups which begin the same way, surround MyGroup with asterisks instead of quotation marks.